# MySQL query analyzer

Tags: mysql

Is there a tool to analyze query more thoroughly than EXPLAIN allows? Something like SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Other than PROCEDURE ANALYSE, nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Take a look also to show profile(s)  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

Comment: There is - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/query-profiler.html

Comment: +1 on the devart tool, works really good.

Answer (score 3):

JetProfiler has a good GUI for explaining queries, and letting you tweak the query in real time.

Answer (score 2):

[sqlyog](http://www.webyog.com) is a best gui tool for query. And there is `Query Profiler` which gives these informations when you execute a query:

- Explain result.
- Explain Extended.
- Change Of Status Variables Due ToExecution Of Query.
- SHOW PROFILE Result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an interface that lets you see which commands are causing errors check out mysql workbench.  However, if you're looking for a tool to tell you what commands are slowing down your query, take a look at [this](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Percona's MySQL toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/). It contains lots of useful tools, including testing queries in large volumes, not just one at a time, and a tool for showing query plans graphically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "[MySQL Explain Explain](http://mxx.mnstrl.org)" can help too (verbose version of MySQL `EXPLAIN` command, forkable on [github](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/mysql-xplain-xplain)).